# Trying to administer network setting of server via netsh

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-access

I am trying to configure the LAN settings of a Windows 2008 server remotely via netsh. I've been trying this command (issued at the client) assuming the IP address of the server is 192.168.0.1:

```
netsh -r 192.168.0.1  -u 192.168.0.1\Administrator -p password lan show config
```

but I keep getting the following message:

WARNING: Could not obtain host information from machine [192.168.0.1]. Some commands may not be available.

The RPC server is unavailable.

Am I understanding the command above properly? Is there a step or two that I missed in setting this up?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. The Routing and Remove Access service on the server is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If routing and remote access is enabled and you're still getting an RPC error it may be the OS' firewall at play.  I vaguely remember something like this when messing with Server Core installs.  If you have physical access to the server, just to test, try

`netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off`

And try the command again.

If that fixes it then you'll need to punch a hole in the firewall for the RPC server (port 135 if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for a similar solution. has anything ever been found for this?

I need to be able to change the IP address, gateway and DNS server information on a group of remote servers. It appears that netsh should support this, but I'm having the same problems as the original poster -- I'm receiving the message that "some commands may not be available".

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" is enabled in your network connection properties.